# How to pass headers to auth-url in nginx ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress

What is the correct way to pass auth header in auth-url for external auth? Below is my current nginx ingress config：

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-cache-key: $remote_user$http_authorization
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers: Authorization
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-signin: mydomain/signin
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-url: mydomain/check
```

Traffic will first go to /signin, and after my external oauth signin, it will go to my another /redirect endpoint where I send Authorization header, and redirect back to the original url. But next time when traffic goes to original url and hits /check, it does not pass Authorization header to my /check endpoint so it fails the auth verification again.  I thought nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-response-headers would pass the header for me but it did not work. Do you know how to pass header in my case?

Many thanks!

Comment: According to [the fine manual](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations/#external-authentication), it's `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-proxy-set-headers`: _the name of a ConfigMap that specifies headers to pass to the authentication service_

Comment: Tried to use auth-proxy-set-headers to pass auth header but no luck either

Comment: I am also not able to receive authorization header at the auth-url endpoint.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried setting specifically the header inside the `auth-snippet` annotation?

```yaml
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-snippet: |
    proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
```